# Feedback on The Loop: Adding review guidance to the help center

Tags: discussion, review, help-center, announcements, the-loop

I just posted to our blog about our recent [review guidance work for the help center](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/11/19/the-loop-adding-review-guidance-to-the-help-center/).

In the post, I go into detail about our motivations, thinking, and the work that took place to complete this project.

Please take a moment to give it a read. Let us know what you think went well with this project and how we may improve with similar projects in the future. We are interested in your thoughts and questions regarding this project!

Comment: [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/11/19/the-loop-adding-review-guidance-to-the-help-center/) currently doesn't show any tags at the bottom - is that intended?