# Is the "Congratulations" message in the FP Queue misguiding use of VLQ?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

There have been numerous discussions about the merits (or otherwise) of the "Very Low Quality" (VLQ) flag for *questions*, such as [here on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328575/is-the-vlq-flag-appropriate-for-blatantly-off-topic-questions-here-on-mse), along with many closely related questions on Meta Stack Overflow (and quite probably on other Meta sites, too). Many of these are 'complaints' from users, asking why their VLQ flag was declined.

Many moderators seem to think that the flag is essentially useless for questions, with voting or flagging to close being more appropriate, or raising a red flag for more serious cases.

However, the message given by the system following a successful "known bad" audit in the First Posts queue states that raising just such a flag is one of four "appropriate actions."

[image]

With the recent/ongoing improvements to the [various review queue guidance texts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356853/feedback-on-the-loop-adding-review-guidance-to-the-help-center) (great improvements, IMHO), would now be a good time to 'correct' the Audit System's congratulatory note, to remove all mention of the VLQ flag?

Comment: The VLQ flag on questions and answers basically has to do with the system's quality test - an automatic test which scans the quality of the post (checks for bad capitalization, punctuation, etc.). The flag is only shown on questions that pass the quality test; it's basically a way of telling the system, "hey, you were wrong about judging this as good quality, it's actually of bad quality and should be treated as such".

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog But, IIRC, that banner is shown for *all* known-bad FP audits that are passed. To me, that's the system recommending users to use the flag - much to the chagrin of many moderators.

Comment: The most common complaint as to why mods are often against it on questions is because it provides a circuitous route to actions like closing or deleting - it puts the post into an additional review queue over and beyond what it would otherwise be put into had one cast a close flag or red flag instead. Specifically, it will put the question into Triage (SO) or Low Quality Posts (non-SO), where it then has to be sent to the Close Votes queue, whereas if a close flag had been cast, it would be straight sent to the Close Votes queue.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog So, is it ever an "appropriate action?" And, if not, why is the system telling folks that it is? FP Reviewers can be quite new to the process (500 rep, I think), so why would we want to mis-educate them?

Comment: For reference: [Help Center draft: First posts queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356122/282094) - and your similar question [about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356140/282094).